Apache Iceberg table created via AWS Athena has additional partition layer in s3
I am creating an Apache Iceberg table via AWS Athena using following query
CREATE TABLE poc.users ( user_id int, user_name string, created_ts timestamp)
PARTITIONED BY (day(created_ts))
LOCATION 's3://poc_iceberg/users'
TBLPROPERTIES ( 'table_type'='iceberg', 'vacuum_max_snapshot_age_seconds'='86400', 'write_compression'='snappy', 'format'='parquet', 'vacuum_min_snapshots_to_keep'='1'
)

The table is created successfully, When I insert the data into the Iceberg table I expect the s3 objects to be partitioned by created_ts_day=2024-05-21. But I see an additional partitioning layer above the created_ts_day. e.g: data/0170173f/created_ts_day=2024-05-21/xxxx.parquet.
It is just a random string and I don't understand what it is related to. The metadata shows only the created_ts as parition-spec. Can anyone help me understand what I am missing?
I expect to have created_ts_day as the base level partitioning in s3.
